# Browser cache not loading new version of ReactJS Single Page App on Cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache, amazon-cloudfront

Every time we deploy a new version of the SPA to an S3 bucket with a Cloudfront distribution we have to manually force our browsers to clear cache and reload.

index.html has no-cache set as below

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

And Cloudfront is set to Use Origin Cache Headers

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to let cloudfront handle the caching and invalidate it after deployment :

```
$ aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
$ aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_WWW_CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths "/*"
```

[invalidate-the-cloudfront-cache](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploy-again.html#invalidate-the-cloudfront-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Since Cloudfront uses S3 object metadata, I'd recommend doing it via amazon's interface/cli instead of setting it inside the html file as you have done.

You can do it manually by navigating to your bucket in S3, and clicking your "index.html" file's properties section and

> set "Cache-control" key to "max-age:0, must-revalidate"

I would recommend "max-age:0, must-revalidate" instead of "no-cache" as I've found browsers sometimes don't respect no-cache header. However this is a very personal opinion, so if you know what you are doing with no-cache, you can keep doing it via aws object metadata settings too.

I can also recommend to use aws-cli after deploying a react app to S3 via this command to automate the process. The command below replaces index.html with itself including cache-control header:

```
aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/index.html s3://BUCKET_NAME/index.html --cache-control \"max-age=0, must-revalidate\" --metadata-directive REPLACE --acl public-read
```

Answer (score 0):

Also check your TTLs configured correctly in the Cache behavior.
if Min TTL is configured to other value then 0, it takes preference.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html

Try Cache-control:no-store for index.html if you don't want to cache at all on CloudFront for this particular index.html.